# How to use jQuery within Zurb Foundation for Apps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, zurb-foundation-apps

Zurb foundation for apps uses angular.js and I cannot find a way to override this and be able to use jQuery (or Javascript) in my application.

My head file looks like this

```
<link href="./assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="./assets/js/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/templates.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/routes.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

I have edited the gulp.js file to look like this:

```
  // These files are for your app's JavaScript
  appJS: [
  'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js',
  'node_modules/autosize/src/autosize.js',    
  'client/assets/js/app.js',
  ]
```

So for example: If I would like to use something like this:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {     
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 140) {
        jQuery('body').addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('body').removeClass('active');
    }
```

At this point I get major errors such as:

> app.js:17SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','. Default values in
>   destructuring parameters are currently not supported.
>   foundation.js:9253Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate
>   module application due to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'application' is
>   not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load
>   it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies
>   as the second argument.

Can anyone explain how I can implement jQuery functions within this project?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Also I'd advise against using `./` for locating your assets directory as this is not compatible with Semantic URLs. It is better practice to use a leading `/` to find your assets directory.

Comment: Basically I just want jQuery to work. I followed these instructions http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/21714-how-do-i-use-jquery-with-foundation-for-apps, it just won't recognise my functions when I test it.

Comment: It just keep giving this error: `main.js:1ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery` I added jQuery to the Gulp-file and in my <head>